# looking for a way to download historical factors/coupons of bonds (CUSIPs) from Bloomberg on a monthly basis

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, bloomberg

wanting to download factors and coupons for list of bonds (CUSIPs) from Bloomberg on a reoccurring monthly basis to Excel - suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working?

Comment: I have a CUSIP for MBS security so I entered it as follows and I get historical data =BDP("10569QAD6 Cusip", "MTG_HIST_FACT")  is there a way to have this run on a reoccurring basis on a certain date every month?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You could try to create a scheduled task in windows to open the spreadsheet and create a macro in the spreadsheet to do use the data.